# Error con propiedades reactivas y rutas en Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación Vue con rutas pero al acceder a valores de la instancia `Vue` desde los `templates` del router en un input utilizando `v-model`, cuendo trato de escribir algo en el input me arroja estos dos errores

> [Vue warn]: Cannot set reactive property on undefined, null, or primitive value: undefined

> TypeError: right-hand side of 'in' should be an object, got undefined

Después tengo un botón que ejecuta un metodo que envía los datos del input pero al presionarlo me aparece lo siguiente en la consola

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "saveBook" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
> found in
> --->
> `<Anonymous> <Root>`

Revisé el link que muestra es segundo `warn` pero no logro entender qué hacer con el `$nextTick`.

Edito: En este problema del evento `submit` intenté con `@submit.prevent="this.$root.saveBook()"` pero marca que `this.$root.saveBook()` es `undefined` entonces intenté con `:@submit.prevent="this.$root.saveBook()"` y alternativamente con `v-bind:@submit.prevent="this.$root.saveBook()"` al hacer eso se ejecuta la función sin parar cómo si fuese un bucle o el evento `submit` se activara muchas veces

¿Cómo puedo solucionar estos `warn`? ¿Cual es la forma correcta de enlazar inputs desde el router y la instancia? ¿Por qué el metodo no se ejecuta?

Este es mi código:

Router:

```
Vue.use(VueRouter);
const Questionnaire = { template: `
    <div>
        <form @submit.prevent="saveBook()">
            
                <input v-model="this.$root.titleBook" id="titleBook" type="text" maxlength="200" required>
                
                <input v-model="this.$root.idUrlBook" id="idUrlBook" type="text maxlength="100" required>
                
            <button type="submit">
                Enviar
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>

` };

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        { path: '/questionnaire', component: Questionnaire },
    ]
});
```

Instancia

```
new Vue({
    router,
    el: "#app",
    data:{ 
        // datos de formulario para crear cuestionarios
        titleBook:'',
        idUrlBook:'',
        //
        bookData
    },
    methods : {

        saveBook: function () {
            var vm = this;


                axios.post('php/bookQuery/book.php',this.createdFormData(
                    {
                        typeReq:1,
                        titleBook:this.titleBook,
                        idUrlBook:this.idUrlBook,
                    }
                ))
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    if (response.data.state == true ){
                        M.toast({html: response.data.msg});
                        vm.getBook();

                    } else {
    
                    }
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        },
        getBook: function () {
            var vm = this;
            axios.post('php/bookQuery/book.php',this.createdFormData(
                {
                    typeReq:2,
                }
            ))
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.data);
                if (response.data.state == true ){
                    vm.bookData = response.data.bookData;
                } else {

                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.getBook();
    }
})
```

Comment: Intenta con `this.$root.saveBook()`

Comment: Intenté con `@submit.prevent="this.$root.saveBook()"` pero marca que `this.$root.saveBook()` es `undefined` entonces intenté con `:@submit.prevent="this.$root.saveBook()"` y alternativamente con `v-bind:@submit.prevent="this.$root.saveBook()"` al hacer eso se ejecuta la función sin parar cómo si fuese un bucle o el evento `submit` se activara muchas veces

Comment: Intenta hacer el v-bind en el boton `submit`

Comment: ¿Evitando el evento `submit`? ¿cómo puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Podrias cambiar el tipo del boton a `button`.